# Query on oracle on group by

Tags: oracle

I have two 16 digit cardnumber 
[123456789ABCDEF0],
[123456ABCDEF7890] 
in card table. 
I have two similar bin  [123456] and [123456789] in bin table. I want a query to to count the number of cards grouped by bin

Comment: How do you know which BIN those CARDNUMBERs belong to? Both of them start with 123456.

Comment: thats is my question, 
One Bin is 123456 
and other Bin is 123456789 
I want a query that will make group of 123456789 cards and 123456 cards

Comment: So you want to know how to count based on the longest match?

Comment: You didn't understand what I'm saying. Card **123456**789ABCDEF0 and card **123456**ABCDEF7890 both have bin **123456**, but 123456789ABCDEF0 might also be counted for bin 123456789. So my question is: which bin do those two cards belong to?

Comment: The card should be counted in longest bin

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the longest matching bin for each card you could use something like this:

```
select c.card_number,
  min(b.bin) keep (dense_rank first order by length(b.bin) desc) as bin
from bins b
left join cards c
on c.card_number like b.bin || '%'
group by c.card_number;
```

and then further aggregate those results:

```
select bin, count(card_number)
from (
  select c.card_number,
    min(b.bin) keep (dense_rank first order by length(b.bin) desc) as bin
  from bins b
  left join cards c
  on c.card_number like b.bin || '%'
  group by c.card_number
)
group by bin;
```

With some sample data in CTEs, the first query gives:

```
-- CTEs for sample data
with cards (card_number) as (
            select '123456789ABCDEF0' from dual
  union all select '123456789ABCDEF1' from dual
  union all select '123456ABCDEF7890' from dual
  union all select '123456ABCDEF7891' from dual
  union all select '123456ABCDEF7892' from dual
),
bins (bin) as (
            select '123456' from dual
  union all select '123456789' from dual
  union all select '2345' from dual
)
-- actual query
select c.card_number,
  min(b.bin) keep (dense_rank first order by length(b.bin) desc) as bin
from bins b
left join cards c
on c.card_number like b.bin || '%'
group by c.card_number;

CARD_NUMBER      BIN      
---------------- ---------
123456789ABCDEF0 123456789
123456789ABCDEF1 123456789
123456ABCDEF7890 123456   
123456ABCDEF7891 123456   
123456ABCDEF7892 123456   
                 2345
```

and the second gives:

```
BIN       COUNT(CARD_NUMBER)
--------- ------------------
123456789                  2
2345                       0
123456                     3
```

I've used a left outer join between the tables so you get the zero count for bins with no cards, but you might not want that.